# how can i use 'node_modules' directly with 'yarn berry'

Tags: node-modules, yarnpkg, vite

i used node_modules to run a script and, copied node_modules to 'dist' to import modules

'packages.json'

```
"scrips":{
    "start" : "node ./node_modules/storybook/server/index.js"
}
```

and
'vite.config.ts'

```
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";

      copy({
            targets: [
                {
                    src: "node_modules/lit-element/",
                    dest: "dist",
                },
```

but with yarn berry, doesn't make 'node_modules'

so, how can i do that things before i used node_modules directly

Answer (score 4):

You can add [nodeLinker: node-modules](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nodeLinker) in your `.yarnrc.yml`, such that the yarn will generate the `node_modules` directory as before.