starting NestJS with Yarn Berry(not NPM) gets import error
I used to use NestJS with NPM.
But now, I wanna try Yarn Berry so I start new NestJS project with yarn.
And it's not going well...
Here is my commands and error.
Generate NestJS application
% nest new yarnProject
? Which package manager would you ❤️  to use? yarn

...

  Successfully created project yarn-project

Start NestJS application
% yarn install
% yarn start

Error
node:buffer:587
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
            ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "list[2]" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type string ('app.controller.d.ts')
    at Function.concat (node:buffer:587:13)
    at node:internal/fs/rimraf:144:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at node:internal/fs/rimraf:143:5
    at /Users/shin/TodaysProject/yarn-project/.pnp.cjs:12946:13 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v20.17.0

I thought it could be solved by node version.
So I changed node version from 20.17.0 to 18.20.4.
But it didnt' work and error changed.
src/app.controller.ts:1:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app.module.ts:1:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app.service.ts:1:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.ts:1:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 4 error(s).

Is there anyone who can solve this problem?

This looks like a bug in nest cli. I'm able to reproduce TS error ('@nestjs/common', etc) but not node error (ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE). TS error is specific to TS template. It's not Yarn that is the problem but PnP, TS fails to resolve typings. You can avoid this with https://stackoverflow.com/a/68574153/3731501 , but it likely defies the purpose of using yarn. I'd suggest to open an issue

@nsetjs/cli v10.4.7, yarn v4.5.1, node v20.18.0, unable to reproduce the issue. Can you share the versions you're using? You can also try yarn nest start.

I solved this problem by downgrading Typescript version from 5.x.x to 4.x.x.
